# Get stream meta data from receiver app chromeCast

Tags: android, kotlin, chromecast

i am developing chromeCast application. I need to get metadata from receiver app of currently playing stream, i am able to connect, play, pause etc but couldn't get current live stream meta data. Is that even possible? can i get meta data in my android app from chromeCast?

Here is my try :

```
 override fun onApplicationMetadataChanged(p0: ApplicationMetadata?) {
        super.onApplicationMetadataChanged(p0)
        Log.d(">>>>{p0?.name}")
    }
```

but it never get called, can someone please guide me?